# Why does my image.Setonclicklistener which is dynamically created not work with <ScrollView> in xml and inherited parent gesture class

Tags: java, android, gestures

This is my first android app and i am having trouble getting an activity to recognise the onclick event on a dynamically created view....However, the activity inherits from a Gesture parent Class and also the XML for this activity has a scrollview...

Below is the code for my Activity:

```
public class TypeTwoActivity extends GestureActivity {

    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
    int f = 0;

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            /*it needs to return true if we don't want
            to ignore rest of the gestures*/
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_two);
        setTemplateType(getTT2());
        setCurrentClassificationLevel(getCL1());
        setHasGottenToMorePage(getHasGottenToMorePage());
        gestureDetector = GetGesture();

        if (getCurrentClassificationLevel() == getCL1())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CategoryTable.length; i++)
            {
                final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                final ImageView image = createCategoryImage(CategoryTable[i][0],i,CategoryTable[i][1]);
                //gestureDetector =

                if ( CategoryTable[i].equals(CatEO) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            //setCurrentAppName(CatEO);
                            //recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                            Toast.makeText(TypeTwoActivity.this,
                                    "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if ( CategoryTable[i].equals(CatM) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            setCurrentAppName(CatM);
                            recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if ( CategoryTable[i].equals(CatP) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            setCurrentAppName(CatP);
                            // Clear Content on activity
                            recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if ( CategoryTable[i].equals(CatSh) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            setCurrentAppName(CatSh);
                            // Clear Content on activity
                            recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if ( CategoryTable[i].equals(CatSp) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            setCurrentAppName(CatSp);
                            // Clear Content on activity
                            recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if ( CategoryTable[i].equals(CatWTS) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            setCurrentAppName(CatWTS);
                            // Clear Content on activity
                            recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (CategoryTable[i].equals(CatTTO) )
                {
                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            setCurrentAppName(CatTTO);
                            // Clear Content on activity
                            recreateActivityCompat(TypeTwoActivity.this);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    //DynamicGestures(image);
                }
                //layout.addView(btn);
                layout.addView(image);
            }
        }
        else if(getCurrentClassificationLevel() == getCL2())
        {
            setCurrentClassificationLevel(getCL3());

            String PageName = getCurrentAppName();
            int TableLength = 0;
            String[] CurrentTable = null;

            switch(PageName)
            {
                case CatEO:
                    TableLength = EatingOutTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = EatingOutTable;
                    break;
                case CatM:
                    TableLength = MoreTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = MoreTable;
                    break;
                case CatP:
                    TableLength = PropertyTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = PropertyTable;
                    break;
                case CatSh:
                    TableLength = ShoppingTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = ShoppingTable;
                    break;
                case CatSp:
                    TableLength = SportsTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = SportsTable;
                    break;
                case CatTTO:
                    TableLength = ThingsToDoTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = ThingsToDoTable;
                    break;
                case CatWTS:
                    TableLength = WhereToStayTable.length;
                    CurrentTable = WhereToStayTable;
                    break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < TableLength; i++)
            {
                final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                final Button btn = createCategoryButton(CurrentTable[i],i );
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        // Go to Post Type Template
                        SwipingCode(getTemplate4(), R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
                    }
                });
                layout.addView(btn);
            }
        }
        else if(getCurrentClassificationLevel() == getCL3()) {

        }
    }
}
```

Below is the XML for that activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_type_two"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cartoonnetworknuc.whatsoncy.TypeTwoActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally this is the inherited parnet Gesture class:

```
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class GestureActivity extends BaseSwipeAnimationPage {

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureObject;

public GestureDetectorCompat GetGesture() { return gestureObject; }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gesture);

    gestureObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LearnGesture());
}

public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event)
{
    this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}



class LearnGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX , float velocityY)
    {
        boolean GoRight = event2.getX() < event1.getX();
        boolean GoLeft  = event2.getX() > event1.getX();
        boolean GoDown  = event2.getY() > event1.getY();
        boolean GoUp    = event2.getY() < event1.getY();

        float HorizontalLength = Math.abs( event2.getX() - event1.getX() );
        float VerticalLength   = Math.abs( event2.getY() - event1.getY() );;

        if( GoRight && GoUp )
        {
            if(HorizontalLength > VerticalLength)
            {
                //Going Right
                MoveRight(null);
            }
            else
            {
                // Going Up
                MoveUp(null);
            }
        }
        else
        if( GoRight && GoDown )
        {
            if(HorizontalLength > VerticalLength)
            {
                //Going Right
                MoveRight(null);
            }
            else
            {
                // Going Down
                MoveDown(null);
            }
        }
        else
        if( GoLeft && GoUp )
        {
            if(HorizontalLength > VerticalLength)
            {
                //Going Left
                MoveLeft(null);
            }
            else
            {
                // Going Up
                MoveUp(null);
            }
        }
        else
        if( GoLeft && GoDown )
        {
            if(HorizontalLength > VerticalLength)
            {
                //Going left
                MoveLeft(null);
            }
            else
            {
                // Going down
                MoveDown(null);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

    public void MoveDown(View view)
    {
        this.SwipeDown( this.NextPage("Down") );
    }

    public void MoveUp(View view)
    {
        this.SwipeUp( this.NextPage("Up") );
    }

    public void MoveLeft(View view)
    {
        this.SwipeLeft( this.NextPage("Left") );
    }

    public void MoveRight(View view)
    {
        this.SwipeRight( this.NextPage("Right") );
    }
}
```

At present with the above code I can scroll up and down and I can gesture  left, right....but i do not know how to get my dynamically create images views with the setonclicklistener to work.....At present nothing happens

Any help would be very greatly apprietiated
Thanks